# How to suppress unnecessary xml namespace prefix declaration?

Tags: xml, xslt, msxml

I receive this xml

```
<message xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elem1 id="att1">
    <elem2 i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </elem1>
</message>
```

and I need to transform it to this using xslt (prefix changed on nil attribute)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elem1 id="att1">
    <elem2 xsi:nil="true"/>
  </elem1>
</message>
```

I am aware that there is no semantic difference in these two. I have no control over the xml received and am informed that the output cannot have namespace declarations, other than on the root.
I have tried this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.ns1.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  exclude-result-prefixes="i">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@i:nil">
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I get this from it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elem1 id="att1">
    <elem2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </elem1>
</message>
```

The i prefix declaration on elem2 is unnecessary and not allowed by my client.
I can only modify the stylesheet.
Is this possible?

Comment: I think we need to know if the `i:nil` attribute can appear on other elements besides `elem2`, and whether it can ever be `false`. And also in the case it is `true` whether its parent element  can have other attributes and/or child nodes (clearly, it cannot have a text node but other children are not precluded by it).

Comment: The nil attribute may appear on any "leaf" element in a large document i.e. an element containing other attributes but not child elements. It is never false, only true. A value of false is implied by the presence of a text value. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Any additional attributes are in the default namespace.

Comment: That makes sense. I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're copying the parent element and that means (in XSLT 1.0) you're copying its namespaces too.

Try perhaps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="i">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@i:nil]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name() ='i:nil')] | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elem1 id="att1">
    <elem2 i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  </elem1>
</message>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ns1.com"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="i ns1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:elem2">
        <elem2 xsi:nil="{@i:nil}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.ns1.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elem1 id="att1">
    <elem2 xsi:nil="true" />
  </elem1>
</message>
```

Comment: This was my original answer. But it won't work if `elem2` has additional attributes and/or child nodes.

Comment: I concur that your current answer is more generic. But I took the OP's input XML verbatim.

Comment: Well, with that logic, why don't you simply hardcode the `true` value? What's the point of copying the original value when you assume it cannot be `false`? In fact, what's point of doing the transformation at all? You could just send an output document that you prepared in advance.